# Uploaded video to vimeo

Tags: vimeo-android

I have uploaded video to vimeo but get an message"This video will be available for viewing shortly" if the file size is big.
For video of 2/3 secs it does not show this kind of message.
Please can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

that it not an error message, but an informational message - your video was uploaded successfully and will be available soon - I'm sure that in the time between your question and this answer the video has probably become available.

What's happening is that after you successfully upload a video to Vimeo the video needs to go through some extra processing, called transcoding. During this process, the video is made available in a variety of different resolutions and file types. For instance, if you upload a 4K video, that video may not be consumable by someone on a low end device that doesn't have a 4K screen. So during the transcode state, your video will be converted into resolutions lower than 4K so that others can enjoy your video. In addition, your video needs to be made available not just in MP4 streaming, but in adaptive streaming technologies such as HLS and DASH.

Short video files (2-3 seconds like you mentioned) can go through the transcoding process fairly quickly. The larger the video file the longer this process takes.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. But its been four five days, and it still shows this message for more than 1  min of video.

Comment: Hello Kevin ,can u help with vimeo upload process in android ??